Is there a different way to set-up multiple git profiles for bitbucket?
I currently have my config file for ssh set up as follows:
Host bitbucket.org-account1
  HostName bitbucket.org
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_account1
  IdentitiesOnly yes

Host github.com-personal
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_personal
  IdentitiesOnly yes

Host *
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

When I am trying to clone from my account1 account, it keeps prompting me for my id_rsa key, instead of the id_rsa_account1 key. This is the ssh command I am trying to run:
git clone git@bitbucket.org:account1/my.cool.project.git

Any idea what may be causing the confusion between the RSA keys? Have I misconfigured the SSH config file?

This is both a problem with your ~/.ssh/config file and with the way you think you're using it.
First: Since bitbucket.org and github.com are different services, you don't need to do separate keys, or the -account1/-personal/whatever part of the Host definition. Those are only necessary if you're using multiple accounts on the same service.
Second: Your ~/.ssh/config defines Host bitbucket.org-account1, but your clone command doesn't use bitbucket.org-account1. SSH won't use the settings for bitbucket.org-account1 if you don't tell it to.
You can fix this in one of three ways:

Set the same key on both services, then remove everything from ~/.ssh/config
In ~/.ssh/config, change bitbucket.org-account1 to bitbucket.org, and github.com-personal to github.com, and leave the rest as it is
Use bitbucket.org-account1 or github.com-personal in your clone commands, every time

